# Django ImportError: No module named middleware

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-middleware

I am using Django version 1.8 and python 2.7. I am getting the following error after running my project.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named middleware
[26/Aug/2015 20:34:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

This is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for collageapp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '******************************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'manageApp',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'rest_framework',
)

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
)


ROOT_URLCONF = 'collageapp.urls'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'collageapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'college_app',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have tried surfing the error but in vain. My same code is working fine in other machine.

Comment: Does this error have anything to do with sql file migrations or workspace.xml?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open up a python shell by running `python manage.py shell` in your project directory.

Run the following commands **one at a time** in the python shell:

```
>>> from corsheaders.middleware import CorsMiddleware
>>> from oauth2_provider.middleware import OAuth2TokenMiddleware
>>> from django.contrib.auth.middleware import SessionAuthenticationMiddleware
```

One of the lines should give you an error like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named middleware
```

The line that gives you that error is the missing module that is giving you the problem.

To find the path where the modules are searched, do

```
>>> import sys; sys.path
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't know how to use the python shell, you could just remove the following lines in your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` one at a time until you don't get that error anymore:

```
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
```

---

Just reinstall the package that gave you the error.

`django.contrib.auth.middleware` -> `django`

`corsheaders.middleware` -> `corsheaders`

`oauth2_provider.middleware` -> `oauth2_provider`

Comment: Thanks for providing a "sane" approach to the problem. I had a similar one and you made my day :)

Comment: @PaoloStefan Glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have all of the supporting packages installed where they can be found. I've run into problems where there are multiple Python interpreters installed, and was inadvertently running Django with one interpreter while installing packages with another. The other thing I would verify is that you have the same versions of the packages on both machines. Pay close attention to  `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` and   `oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware` since they are not part of Django.

Comment: I have installed all these packages I am still getting the error message. I am using django 1.7. Following is my freeze list: 
defusedxml==0.4.1
Django==1.7
django-cors-headers==1.3.1
django-tastypie==0.13.3
lxml==3.6.4
oauth2-provider==0.0
Pillow==3.4.2
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.2
(env) mike@mike-VirtualBox:/var/www/CordeliaHanelBackend-master$

Comment: You should probably post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation i did the following:

1. Inspect the settings.py file
2. Check on the middleware section for any part that could have been deleted ,accidentally and rectify.

For my case the following had been deleted:

```
django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware
```