# Python Import Error - Run unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, runtime-error

Why am I getting import error for a module I have in the project. All the packages are under the project, they all have __init __.py and other scripts do not give the same error. Python version is 3.6. Code was written in Unix environment.

Here is the import error I get. I am trying to run a test here.

```
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_SMSHandler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/sevvalboylu/server/app/api/test_SMSHandler.py", line 11, in <module>
    from middleware.services import Sender
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'middleware'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ImportError: No module named middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230490/django-importerror-no-module-named-middleware)

Comment: middleware is not found. Try "pip install middleware" first

Comment: Middleware is a pyhton package and it is under the project path. Im afraid its not the problem here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a project's root path in [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

From the docs ([Modules - The Module Source Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path))

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory
>     when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

If this solution doesn't work for you, please post the project's tree to make it easier find the problem.

Comment: I didn't actually understand your suggestion here, do you mean I don't have middleware in my PYTHONPATH? How would I check that?

Comment: @sevcodes yes, I mean just that. You can get PYTHONPATH content with the following command:  `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: check if your proejct's root directory, that contains `middleware` is there

Comment: Okay I checked it, middleware is not there. How can I add it to path?

Comment: Nvm I found the way, thanks for the idea! Tagging this one as the answer now

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a similar problem with import error when running unit tests (with correct importable structure), but the cause and the solution are different to described in the answer above. Still this is relevant and may help somebody.

In my case I have structure like that (`__init__.py` present but omitted below for brevity):

```
mypkg
  \-- foo.py
another
tests
  \-- some
        \-- <tests here>
      mypkg  <--- same name as top level module mypkg
        \-- test_a.py
```

When running from top level directory imports in `test_a.py` of modules from `mypkg` were failing:

```
# test_a.py
from mypkg import foo  # causes ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypkg.foo'
```

Renaming `mypkg` folder under `tests` folder into something else solved the problem.